# Add html markup to multiple custom fields with ACF, array custom fields not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'd like to add h2 tags before and /h2 tags after multiple ACF fields. The fields are 'kopregel_onder_slider' and 'kopregel_bij_testimonials'.

This works fine for one field at once only, for example:

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=kopregel_onder_slider', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

To minimize code length, I want to re-use the code again for the second ACF field, so I've created an array '$field_name' with the two ACF fields.

I've replaced:

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=kopregel_onder_slider', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

with the array:

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name={$field_name}', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

but it is not working.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=$field_name', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

Doesn't work either.

```
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field  ) {

    $field_name = array("kopregel_onder_slider", "kopregel_bij_testimonials");

    if (strpos($value, "<h2>") !== 0 ) {
        $ervoor = "<h2>";
        $erachter = "</h2>";
        $value = $ervoor.$value.$erachter;

    return $value;
    }
}

add_filter('acf/update_value/name={$field_name}', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

Comment: You either need an add_filter call for every single field - or you don’t limit this to specific fields to begin with, and then decide whether to modify the value or return it unchanged _inside_ the callback function, based on whether the passed field is one of those you are interested in or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the PHP variable in single quote.

PHP won't use additional processing to interpret what is inside the single quote. when you use double quotes PHP has to parse to check if there are any variables within the string.

Please try to update you filter name within double quote as below and give a try.

`add_filter("acf/update_value/name={$field_name}", "my_acf_update_value", 10, 3);`

Hope this will resolve the issue.